# Why calling Dao from an interface breaks the observation on ViewModel?

Tags: android, viewmodel, dao, android-room, android-livedata

I have a problem when I try to call `DAO` from an interface.

Here is where I call observer method:

```
mCategories = ViewModelProviders.of(FragmentCategories.this).get(CategoriesViewModel.class);
//...
mCategories.getCategories(context).observe(this, listC -> {
            ArrayList<Category> newList=new ArrayList<>(listC);
            final DiffUtil.DiffResult result = DiffUtil.calculateDiff(
                    new CategoriesDif(list,newList), false);
            list.clear();
            list.addAll(newList);
            result.dispatchUpdatesTo(myAdapter);
            onItemsLoadComplete();
        });
```

Here is when I add object to DB:

```
private ColorPicked colorPicked = null;
//...
if (x) {
        colorPicked = () - > {
        Category c = new Category();
        c.name = input.toString();
        new AddCategoryOrLinkToDB().execute(c);
        colorPicked = null;
        dialog.dismiss();};

    new ColorChooserDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this, R.string.color_palette)
    .titleSub(R.string.colors)
    .dynamicButtonColor(false)
    .show(MainActivity.this);
} else {
      Category c = new Category();
      c.name = input.toString();
      new AddCategoryOrLinkToDB().execute(c);
      colorPicked = null;
      dialog.dismiss();
}

//...
@Override
public void onColorChooserDismissed(@NonNull ColorChooserDialog dialog) {
    if (colorPicked != null) {
        colorPicked.chosen();
    }
}
```

> Why, if I call `new AddCategoryOrLinkToDB().execute(c)` from
>   `colorPicked`, the observer does not trigger and stops working?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem.

In the ViewModel I used the method `observeForever`, replacing it with `observe` I solved.